# Nginx Proxy Pass Working with Curl, not with Browser

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have nginx (1.15) running inside docker container in swarm mode inside vagrant. Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

    #gzip  on;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1200s;
    proxy_send_timeout          3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout          3600s;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is my generated config file /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    location /jarvis/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s;
        rewrite ^/jarvis(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://jarvis:8000;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }

    location /nginx/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s;
        rewrite ^/nginx(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://nginx:80;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
```

When I curl *http://localhost:8002/jarvis/health/* inside a container, its working fine.

But when I access from  browser, nginx throws following error in the log and 404 in the browser.

```
2018/10/01 05:11:07 [error] 61#61: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/jarvis/health" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.255.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /jarvis/health HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8002"
10.255.0.2 - - [01/Oct/2018:05:11:07 +0000] "GET /jarvis/health HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
2018/10/01 05:11:07 [error] 61#61: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.255.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8002"
10.255.0.2 - - [01/Oct/2018:05:11:07 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

When I make both the config files into one, it works fine from curl as well as from browser. Also, when I use upstream in app.conf (this will not fit my requirement as IP's are dynamic), it works fine with curl and browser.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, I am stucked with problem for last 3days, and not able to find any solution

Comment: Port 80 in your Nginx configuration and 8002 later. I guess it can be related to your problem.

Comment: I exposed the port 8002 for nginx 80 port running inside container, if I give server_name as localhost, it works. But how to make it work without server_name, since I will be deploying using multiple dns

Comment: You are giving very confusing information: `server_name` is not used in the configuration you provided.

Comment: I mean, I tried with server_name option after posting and it worked.